# Setting background colour for a tool button

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to set background colour for a Plasma component, specifically the keyboard layout button used in the KDE lock screen. (The button is sometimes poorly visible on a light background, so I'm trying to darken it).

Here's full contents of KeyboardLayoutButton.qml I'm trying to modify:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1 as QQC

import org.kde.plasma.components 2.0 as PlasmaComponents

import org.kde.plasma.workspace.keyboardlayout 1.0

PlasmaComponents.ToolButton {
    id: kbLayoutButton

    iconName: "input-keyboard"
    implicitWidth: minimumWidth
    text: layout.currentLayoutDisplayName

    Accessible.name: i18ndc("plasma_lookandfeel_org.kde.lookandfeel", "Button to change keyboard layout", "Switch layout")

    visible: layout.layouts.length > 1

    onClicked: layout.nextLayout()

    KeyboardLayout {
          id: layout
              function nextLayout() {
              var layouts = layout.layouts;
              var index = (layouts.indexOf(layout.currentLayout)+1) % layouts.length;
              layout.currentLayout = layouts[index];
          }
    }
}
```

Now I can place a semi-transparent Rectangle *inside* `kbLayoutButton`, and it's visible there, but it doesn't improve visibility of the button text because it is placed *above* the text ad only lowers the contrast. I want to place a rectangle *below* the button.

It is my understanding that I need to make the button a child of a coloured rectangle.

```
Rectangle {
   color: "black"
   PlasmaComponents.ToolButton {
     // full content of kbLayoutButton
   }
}
```

However when I try to do that, the button stops being visible altogether. Same thing when I try to wrap it in an `Item`.

I'm very new to QML and cannot seem to find any clue. How do I set the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with plasma components, but did you give the `Rectangle` a size? Try this:

```
Rectangle {
    implicitWidth: toolButton.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: toolButton.implicitHeight
    color: "black"

    PlasmaComponents.ToolButton {
        id: toolButton
        // full content of kbLayoutButton
    }
}
```